# Can't refresh using VBA a pivot table attached to a table

Tags: vba, excel

I converted a range of cells to a table, called Table1. Then I inserted a pivot table and then I inserted this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim pt As PivotTable
  Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
  pt.PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```

I'm getting an error 1004. The DataSource is 'Table1'

Answer (score 0):

I moved the code from `Worksheet_Change` event, to a `Sub` that you can call from a button, otherwise it will fire everytime someone modifies or touches anywhere in this Sheet.

I defined the "**PivotSrc_Range**" that is Set-up to "**Table1**", and is set-up to the `PivotCache`, this way, everytime someone modifies or adds a data to "**Table1**", the `PivotCache` changes, and the `PivotTable` will be modified once you call the `Sub` below:

```
Sub UpdatePivot()

Dim sht1                            As Worksheet
Dim pt                              As PivotTable
Dim PvtCache                        As PivotCache
Dim PivotSrc_Range                  As Range

' modify to your sheet name (I prefer not to use ActiveSheet)
Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

' modify to your Table's name
Set PivotSrc_Range = sht1.Range("Table1")

' set the Pivot Cache
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PivotSrc_Range, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set pt = sht1.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

On Error GoTo 0
If pt Is Nothing Then

    ' create a new Pivot Table in "Sheet1" sheet, start from Cell I1
    Set pt = sht1.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=sht1.Range("I1"), TableName:="PivotTable1")
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range (data in Table1)
    pt.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
    pt.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't go past the pt.ChangePivotCache line

Comment: 34 including the header line

Comment: did you modify the sheet name to match yours ? is your table formatted as table ? and named "Table1" ?

Comment: can u share on dropbox or something ? since I cant duplicate your error. (maybe a screen-shot with your Table data)